# GIT перемещение изменений с одной ветки на другую

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

В репозитории есть только одна ветка "master" на ней я сделал правку файла, при использовании команды `git status` отредактируемый файл подсвечивается как

> modified:   app/Models/Page.php

В ходе тестирование решено не отправлять правку в мастер, но при этом нужно ее сохранить. Так вот как правильно создать новую ветку и на нее отправить текущую правку, так чтобы оно не ушло в мастер, но сохранилось допустим в новой ветке "new"
Я так понимаю, что алгоритм действия должен выглядить примерно так:

Делаешь ветку, встаешь на нее, комитишь и готово:

```
git branch new  
git checkout -b new
git add *
git commit -m "trash"
git push origin new
```

Или не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git status`:

> modified: app/Models/Page.php

```bsh
git checkout -b feature
git commit -am "Add feature"
```

После фиксирования изменений правки будут только в ветке `feature`.

Comment: что означает -а всё добавить?

Comment: @Domilola Добавление параметра `-a` в команду `git commit` заставляет Git автоматически индексировать каждый уже отслеживаемый на момент коммита файл, позволяя обойтись без `git add`.

Comment: Можно через `git stash`.